Issue with Uploading Files with Long Paths (>260 chars) in Web App on Windows
Windows has a long-standing problem with paths longer than 260 chars.
For example, I have the folder with the following path E:\tickets\test_uploading\newaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa this path has a length of 243 chars, and I have the following file in the folder: TEST1-2024-05-17-18-09-30-001.data. So in total, the file path is 278 chars.
In File Explorer, it looks like a regular file but in the properties or by using the dir /x command you can find its short name and path.
enter image description here
If you try to upload this file (drag and drop or open) browser will show the truncated file name:
enter image description here
I tried to get the full name (maybe from path), but there is no way to get the full path of the file because the browser policy prohibits it.
How can I handle this case? Can I check if I can preserve the original file name on uploading?
